# How to get list of Employee name by entering Manager Name in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server

**Requirement:**

We have list of all employee's in the the excel sheet. We need to export this Employee list in the SharePoint. So whenever we will type Manager name then it should display the list of employees whomever reporting to respective manager.

Condition is "The manager should not contain more than 20 employee, it can be less. If it is more than 20 employee then automatic email should be trigger."

How to complete this requirement.

Can you share the steps how to implement this requirements?

Answer (score 1):

You can maintain a custom SharePoint list "EmployeeDetails" to Hold the Employee details in it with the following fields.
Fields:

- Employee - Single User Column
- Manager -  Single User Column

**Solution 1**:

You could take the reference of the jQuery plugin called DataTable, where the search is very reliable.
[Using jQuery DataTable To Display SharePoint 2013 List Data On SharePoint Site Pages](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/using-jquery-datatable-to-display-sharepoint-list-data-on-share/)

**Solution 2**:

Alternatively You can have a client side people picker with a button to search in a SharePoint Site page. Design an html table to display the Employee in the same page and refer the source in a content/script editor web part.
When the search button is clicked, call the REST endpoint with your all conditions to the "EmployeeDetails" list and display the items Employee fields on the table.

Solution 2 would satisfy your requirement.